Developing a Continuous Sequence Recorder Using Selenium and WebSocket
I want to create a sequence recorder application. My goal is to take a URL from the user on the client side and open it in a browser on the server side. The user interacts with the server-side browser through WebSocket, drawing the PNGs received from the server onto a canvas, and performs the desired actions. I have accomplished this, but when I try to record events using Selenium in the server-side browser, the recording stops whenever the page is refreshed or a different link is clicked.
Essentially, I want to automatically start the Selenium recorder on the server side, and ensure that the recording continues even if the page is refreshed or a login form appears due to dynamic redirects. In the end, I want to obtain a file with the .side extension, like the following:
{
  "id": "38b09777-d8d1-4e07-a985-5a4a300004bf",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "test",
  "url": "http://testphp.vulnweb.com",
  "tests": [
    {
      "id": "3d6ea84f-d64f-4109-92f2-c0c96bafda65",
      "name": "stop",
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "8f5c8c81-3628-4505-b767-856de504999a",
          "comment": "",
          "command": "open",
          "target": "/",
          "targets": [],
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "75978eab-8205-4fe1-84a4-e4030f96afe2",
          "comment": "",
          "command": "setWindowSize",
          "target": "1760x1055",
          "targets": [],
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": "2b218310-7214-45b5-addf-6b137ad04b5e",
          "comment": "",
          "command": "click",
          "target": "linkText=Your profile",
          "targets": [
            ["linkText=Your profile", "linkText"],
            ["css=li:nth-child(5) > a", "css:finder"],
            ["xpath=//a[contains(text(),'Your profile')]", "xpath:link"],
            ["xpath=//div[@id='sectionLinks']/ul/li[5]/a", "xpath:idRelative"],
            ["xpath=//a[contains(@href, 'userinfo.php')]", "xpath:href"],
            ["xpath=//li[5]/a", "xpath:position"],
            ["xpath=//a[contains(.,'Your profile')]", "xpath:innerText"]
          ],
          "value": ""
        },

This is the kind of file I want to generate. However, when I try to do this with Selenium, the recording stops when the browser is refreshed or when I click on the recording screen, and the desired .side file does not get created.
On the other hand, when I perform the same operation with Playwright, the following Playwright code works:
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const clickedElement = event.target;
    const eventDetails = {
        id: generateUUID(),
        command: 'click',
        target: clickedElement.tagName.toLowerCase() + (clickedElement.id ? '#' + clickedElement.id : ''),
        value: ''
    };
    console.log(eventDetails);
    window.localStorage.setItem('recordedEvents', JSON.stringify(window.localStorage.getItem('recordedEvents') ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('recordedEvents')).concat(eventDetails) : [eventDetails]));
});

However, I cannot achieve this with Selenium; here’s my attempted approach:

const clickableElements = await driver.findElements(By.css("body *")); // Select all clickable elements
for (const element of clickableElements) {
    const tagName = await element.getTagName();

    await driver.executeScript(`
        const element = arguments[0];
        element.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const eventDetails = {
                id: "${generateUUID()}",
                command: "click",
                target: "${tagName.toLowerCase()}" + (element.id ? "#" + element.id : ""),
                value: ""
            };
            window.localStorage.setItem('recordedEvents', JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('recordedEvents') || '[]').concat(eventDetails)));
        });
    `, element);
}

Essentially, what I want is for the Selenium recording to start with the browser and automatically capture all inputs. I intend to use this application on my Raspberry system for personal laboratory purposes, and if it works, I plan to develop the application further.
I attempted to implement a sequence recorder using Selenium to capture user interactions on a web page. I expected the recorder to function continuously, even when the page refreshed or navigated to different links. However, I encountered issues where the event recording stopped whenever the page refreshed or a new link was clicked, preventing me from obtaining the desired output file.
